# TypeError: jQuery(...).pajinate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery Pajinate plugin and I'm having troubles.
This script worked fine on my last host, but I had to make a migration and now I'm having some issues.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="template/irs/js/jquery.pajinate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#viagens').pajinate({
        item_container_id : '.content',
        items_per_page : 8,
        start_page: 0,
        nav_label_first : '',
        nav_label_last : '',
        nav_label_prev : '< Anterior',
        nav_label_next : ' Próxima >'
    });
});
</script>
```

And i'm having this error:

> TypeError: jQuery(...).pajinate is not a function

I already tried to use `$` instead of `jQuery` and same results. And yes, I already used the search button but no results.
Can anyone help-me?

Comment: Your `jquery.pajinate.js` file is not being loaded correctly. Check the path is correct.

Comment: Your first line can also be simplified to `$(function(){`. You rarely need to call `$(document).ready(` in JQuery

Comment: Have you ever tryied `paginate` instead of `pajinate`? I think there is a mistaken word in your function.

Comment: I tried "$function(){ ", no results. It's pajinate cuz is the name of the script jquery.pajinate.js. And the path is correct

Comment: check your browser console for other errors.

Comment: I checked my browser console, and this is the only error i found

Comment: Interesting. I think now when you try to call your `jquery.pajinate.js`. There is a possible missing slash `/` before word **template**. Try this:  `<script type="text/javascript" src="/template/irs/js/jquery.pajinate.js"></script>`

Comment: Ok, i tried this slash too. but.. same results

Comment: Are you testing this on a web server or loading it locally from your PC?

Comment: It's in my web server

Comment: Seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/6rdmaexq View your page source in Chrome and click the link for pajinate.js. Does it load?

Comment: Yes, when i click in pajinate.js it loads perfectly, as you can see:
http://charmeturismo.com.br/template/irs/js/jquery.pajinate.js

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have conflict of jquery files. Go to the page source and check if you have more than one verison of jquery files references. Try to use jQuery.noConflict() and here is link to see further detail.
http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/